# Show that $r$ is a spherical curve iff $(1/\kappa)^2+((1/\kappa)'(1/\tau))^2$ is a constant.

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $r(s)$ be a curve parametrized by arc length, and $\kappa,\kappa',\tau$ are non-zero. Show that $r$ is a spherical curve iff $(1/\kappa)^2+((1/\kappa)'(1/\tau))^2$ is a constant.

The teacher gave the hint "center = $r+(1/\kappa)N+(1/\kappa)'(1/\tau)B$". I know how to get the proof from this, but how can we show that this is the center? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Show that the distance $\| r(s) - c \|$, where $c$ is the center, is a constant. (Show that its derivative is zero.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Big Hint: The standard technique in all such differential geometry problems is to write
$$ r = \lambda T + \mu N + \nu B$$
for some functions $\lambda$, $\mu$, and $\nu$. Differentiate, use what you're given, and use the Frenet equations and use the fact that $T,N,B$ form a basis to get three equations.

Comment: But here I don't have $r$, how can I get $λ,μ,ν$ ?

Comment: You don't get them explicitly, but you get equations relating them and their derivatives if you follow my suggestion. The crucial thing is: What do you get if you assume the center of the sphere is $0$ and you differentiate $r\cdot r$?

Comment: I get $λλ'+μμ'+νν'=0$, but I really can't see how I should proceed to the result...

Comment: No, you're not using definitions of the Frenet frame. What is $r'$?

Comment: Oh, let me see...

Comment: $r’=(λ’-μκ)T+(μ’+λκ-ντ)N+(ν’+μτ)B$. If I then use $r\cdot r'=0$, I'll still get $λλ′+μμ′+νν′=0$.

Comment: Yes, you'll need this next. But you're missing the most obvious: $r'=T$!

Comment: I GET IT!! THANKS ~

Comment: Awesome! Very powerful technique, and analogues for surface theory too. If you feel like it, accept the answer so the question doesn't appear still to be open.