# Show that $\textbf{$\gamma$}$ lies on a sphere of radius $r$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, spheres

Let $\textbf{$\gamma$ }(t)$ be a unit-speed curve with $\kappa (t) > 0$ and $\tau (t) \neq 0$ for all $t$.
Show that, if $\textbf{$\gamma$}$ is spherical, i.e., if it lies on the surface of a sphere, then $$\frac{\tau }{\kappa }=\frac{d}{ds}\left (\frac{\dot \kappa}{\tau \kappa^2}\right ) \tag 1$$

Conversely, show that if Eq. $(1)$ holds, then $$\rho^2+(\dot \rho \sigma )^2=r^2$$ 
for some (positive) constant $r$, where $\rho = \frac{1}{\kappa}$ and $\sigma = \frac{1}{\tau}$, and deduce that $\textbf{$\gamma$}$ lies on a sphere of radius $r$. Verify that Eq. $(1)$ holds for Viviani’s curve.

$$$$

---

$$$$

At the second part, I am facing some difficulties at showing that $\textbf{$\gamma$}$ lies on a sphere of radius $r$.

Could you give me some hints how to show it?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

I have done everything besides the verification that Eq. $(1)$ holds for Viviani’s curve.

I have done the following:

The Viviani's curve is $$\gamma (t)=\left (\cos^2 t -\frac{1}{2}, \sin t\cos t , \sin t\right )$$

The curvature is given by the formula $$\kappa =\frac{ \| \gamma '' \times \gamma '\|}{\|\gamma '\|^3}$$

I found that it is equal to $$\kappa =\frac{\sqrt{5+3\cos^2 t}}{(1+\cos^2 t)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Its derivative is $$\kappa '=\frac{6 \cos \sin t (\cos^2 t+2)}{\sqrt{5+3\cos^2 t}(1+\cos^2 t)^{\frac{5}{2}}}$$

The torsion is given by the formula $$\tau =\frac{(\gamma ' \times \gamma '' ) \cdot }{\|\gamma ' \times \gamma '' \|^2}$$

I found that it is equal to $$\tau =\frac{6 \cos t}{5+3 \cos^2 t}$$

Then $$\frac{\kappa '}{\tau \kappa^2}=\frac{\sin t(\cos^2 t+2)(1+\cos^2 t)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\sqrt{5+3 \cos^2 t}}$$

I calculated $$\left ( \frac{\kappa '}{\tau \kappa^2} \right ) '$$ at [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28sqrt%281%2Bcos%5E2%28t%29%29%20%282%2Bcos%5E2%28t%29%29%20sin%28t%29%29%2Fsqrt%285%2B3%20cos%5E2%28t%29%29%29%27) but this is not equal to $$\frac{\tau }{\kappa}$$ What have I done wrong?

Comment: If $\tau = 0$, what does $\frac{\ddot{\kappa}}{\tau \kappa^2}$ mean?

Comment: It should be $\tau (t) \neq 0, \forall t$. I edited it. @JasonDeVito

Comment: I just found this:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455661/show-that-r-is-a-spherical-curve-iff-1-kappa21-kappa1-tau2-is?rq=1, which I think makes this question a duplicate.

Comment: I haven't really uinderstood how we show that $\gamma$ lies on a sphere of radius $r$... I have read the question of your last comment, but I still don't understand it... @JasonDeVito Could you maybe clarify to me what we have to do?

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what in Ted's answer (and the comments following it) that you didn't understand?

Comment: Do we write $r$ in that way because $t, n, b$ consist an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$? @JasonDeVito

Comment: Yes, they are an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  In addition, there are known formulas relating $t',n'$ and $b'$ to $t,n,b$ (called the Frenet-Serre formulas.)

Comment: So, we have $$\gamma=A\textbf{t}+B\textbf{n}+C\textbf{b} \\ \Rightarrow \gamma '=A' \textbf{t}+ A\textbf{t}' +B' \textbf{n} + B\textbf{n}' +C' \textbf{b} +C\textbf{b} ' \ \ \ \ \ (*)$$ 

From the equations Frenet-Serret we have $$\textbf{t}'=\kappa \textbf{n} \\ \textbf{n}'=-\kappa \textbf{t}+\tau \textbf{b} \\ \textbf{b}'=-\tau \textbf{n}$$

Comment: So, we get $$\textbf{t}=A' \textbf{t}+ A\kappa \textbf{n} +B' \textbf{n} + B (-\kappa \textbf{t}+\tau \textbf{b} )+C' \textbf{b} -C\tau \textbf{n} \\ \Rightarrow (A'-B\kappa -1)\textbf{t}+(A\kappa +B'-C\tau ) \textbf{n}+ (B\tau +C')\textbf{b}=0$$ 

Does this mean that $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
A'-B\kappa -1=0\\ 
A\kappa +B'-C\tau=0\\ 
B\tau +C'=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$ ?  @JasonDeVito

Comment: Well, what I would do is try to use the hint that the center is $r + \frac{1}{\kappa} N + \frac{1}{\kappa'} \frac{1}{\tau} B$.  This is a weird hint, because it certainly looks like the "center" depends on t.  So, your first step should be showing that, in fact, the center is independent of $t$.  To do this, take the deriivative of the center using the Frenet-Serre relations.  You should be able to show that the $T$ and $N$  componenets of the derivative vanish automatically, and that th $B$ component vanishes iff equation $(1)$ holds.$ (continued)

Comment: Once you show that, your goal is to show that $\|r-c\|$ is constant.  To do this, write it as $(r-c)\cdot (r-c)$ and differentiate.

Comment: In the paragraph which starts with "Well,...", that should be a $\left( \frac{1}{\kappa}\right)'$, not $\frac{1}{\kappa'}$.

Comment: Ok... I see... Thanks for the help!! :-) $$$$ I edited my initial post... I added what I have tried about the verification of the formula for the Viviani's curve. Could you take a look at it, because I must have done a mistake, but I don't know where... @JasonDeVito

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is a lot easier than what you think: 
Take (1) above:
$$\frac{\tau }{\kappa }=\frac{d}{ds}\left (\frac{\dot \kappa}{\tau \kappa^2}\right ) \tag 1$$

Rewrite this in terms of $\sigma$ and $\rho$
$$\frac{\rho}{\sigma }=\frac{d}{ds}\left (\sigma (-\dot \rho)\right ) = -\frac{d}{ds}\left (\dot{\rho} \sigma \right ) \tag 2$$

Now you're almost done.

Take the derivative of the LHS of your expression:

$$\frac{d}{ds}\left(\rho^2 + (\dot{\rho} \sigma)^2 \right) = 2\rho \dot{\rho} + 2(\dot{\rho} \sigma)\frac{d}{ds}(\dot{\rho} \sigma)$$
But we just figured out what that last term is in terms of $\rho$ so substitute:
$$\frac{d}{ds}\left(\rho^2 + (\dot{\rho} \sigma)^2 \right) = 2\rho \dot{\rho} + 2(\dot{\rho} \sigma)\left(\frac{-\rho}{\sigma}\right)$$
You can now see that
$$\frac{d}{ds}\left(\rho^2 + (\dot{\rho} \sigma)^2 \right) = 0$$

Or in other words $\rho^2 + (\dot{\rho} \sigma)^2$ is a constant (it must be positive, do you see why?). And if you call that constant $r^2$ you are done.

Put $a = \rho N + \sigma \dot{\rho} B$

We have just shown that this vector has a constant length of $r$.
You can use the Frenet equations to show that $\dot{a} = -T = -\dot{\gamma}$

Then it is clear that $\gamma + a$ is a constant vector (the center of the circle) and the path $\gamma$ is at a constant distance $r$ from it.

For Viviani's curve put
$$ \gamma(t) = \left(\frac{r}{2}(1 + \cos t), \frac{r}{2} \sin(t), r \sin(t/2)\right)$$
Which you can get from Wikipedia or Mathworld (remember we have a constant $r$ for our radius).
then
$$ \gamma'(t) = \frac{r}{2}\left(-\sin (t), \cos(t), \cos(t/2)\right)$$
$$ \gamma''(t) = -\frac{r}{2}\left(\cos (t), \sin(t), \sin(t/2)/2\right)$$
This is different from what you have. You need to calculate this out to finish.

For example I get $||\gamma'' \times \gamma'|| = \frac{r^2}{8\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{13 + \cos (t)}$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: $\rho^2 + (\dot{\rho} \sigma)^2$ is a positive constant because it is a sum of squares, right? $$$$ After that, how can we deduce that $\gamma$ lies on a sphere of radius $r$?

Comment: OK sorry for the confusion it's been a few years since I did this stuff. I think I got it all correct now. Construct the vector $a$ and see that (according to Frenet) it's derivative is $-T$. This should be all you need for the last bit.

Comment: Why do we put $a = \rho N + \sigma \dot{\rho} B$ ?

Comment: Because it works! We just saw that this vector has a constant norm. You use that particular combination of $N$ and $B$ to make the Frenet equations work out the right way so that $\dot{a} = -T$. Then everything works out nicely!

Comment: Having shown that $\dot a=-\dot \gamma$ we have that $\dot \gamma +\dot a=0 \Rightarrow \gamma +a=\text{ constant }$. Why is this constant the centre of the circle?

Comment: That is what you conclude. $\gamma$ is a constant distance away from a constant vector in space. That is what it means to be on the surface of a sphere.

Comment: I got stuck right now... Do we conclude that $-a$ is the centre and $\gamma +a=\text{ constant }$ is the radius? Or is $\gamma +a$ the centre?

Comment: The center of the circle is fixed in space (that's $\gamma + a$ for us). It doesn't change. The path $\gamma$ is always at a fixed distance from this center. This means that $|a|$ is constant (and equal to $r$) which we have already shown. This is all you need to show. Your path is at a fixed distance from some fixed point in space. QED.

Comment: I see... I have a question about $a$... Could we find it by writting it as follows $$a=A \cdot t+B\cdot n+C\cdot b$$ and using the Frenet-Serret equations?

Comment: I edited my initial post... I added what I have tried about the verification of the formula for the Viviani's curve. Could you take a look at it, because I must have done a mistake, but I don't know where...

Comment: @MaryStar  I'll take a look and add to the post.

Comment: In my book Viviani's curve is defined as I wrote in my inital post. So, does it only stand if we use the definition you used?

Comment: Can we not use the curve of my initial post because it is not unit-speed?

Comment: You can use the non unit speed curve. You divide out the speed as you have done. Try taking it from where I left it. It all works out right.

Comment: Is the formula for Viviani's curve that I wrote in my initial post and the formula that you used equivalent?

Comment: I think so, it seems to be the same with a different parametrization of $t$.

Comment: I used the formula that you stated but I get $$\|\gamma ''\times \gamma '\|=\frac{r^2\sqrt{3\cos t+13}}{8\sqrt{2}}$$ which is different from yours... I get the vector $$\gamma ''\times \gamma '=\left (-\frac{r^2}{4}\sin t\cos \frac{t}{2}+\frac{r^2}{8}\cos t\sin \frac{t}{2}, \frac{r^2}{8}\sin t\sin \frac{t}{2}+\frac{r^2}{4}\cos t\cos \frac{t}{2}, -\frac{r^2}{4}\right )$$ Have you found the same?