# Necessary and Sufficient Conditions for Curve to lie on 2-Sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves, curvature

State  and  prove  necessary  and  sufficient  conditions  for  a  Frenet  curve
$\gamma :I \to \mathbb{R}^3$
to be contained in some $2$-sphere
$S^2=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3; ||x−c||=r\}$ of centre $c$ and radius $r>0$.

The only one I can think of is the torsion needs be equal to $0$ as only a plane curve can lie on the surface of a two sphere. Would one of the conditions also be that the inner product of the tangent and position vectors must be $0$ (i.e. they are orthogonal) as any bit of tangent vector in the direction of the position would push the curve off the surface?

Comment: Concerning the tangent & the position vectors:  your assertion is basically correct, and can be proven rigorously by taking the derivative of $(\vec{\gamma}(s) - \vec{c}) \cdot (\vec{\gamma}(s) - \vec{c})$ with respect to $s$.

Comment: Only a planar curve can lie on the surface of a sphere? Huh? ... You need to start searching this site more carefully. This question has been answered numerous times. For example: There's [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455661/show-that-r-is-a-spherical-curve-iff-1-kappa21-kappa1-tau2-is). This is also an exercise in my text. :)

Comment: Your text seems to have it all Mr. Shifrin! I shall check out the post you've linked and poke around more (after doing some looking in it I think I've reconstructed the curve from Curvature and Torsion -- so thank you!). @MichaelSeifert thank you for your insight as well, I shall make sure to prove it rigorously!